# Remove xmlns attribute

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have an xml

```
<XML>
   <Client xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.34.00" ></Client>
</XML>
```

How to remove all the attributes in the Client tag in Java.

I used earlier

```
Element element = (Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("Client").item(0);
element.removeAttribute("Version");
element.removeAttribute("xmlns:xsi");
```

The **Version** attribute was removed from the **Client** tag. But **xmlns:xsi** attribute was **NOT** removed.

Does anybody faced any similar issue or know how to approach this problem.

Comment: 1. The XML you have shared is invalid, since the client tag isn't closed.    2. Can you please share your complete code?

Comment: not able to reproduce

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. It works as expected.

Comment: `xmlns:xsi` is not an attribute. It is a _namespace declaration_. If you would like to remove it, search for how to remove a namespace declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You should getOwnerDocument() for node "Client" and do renameNode(nodeClient,null,"Client");
NB: removeAttribute removes "xmlns:xsi", but namespace is stored in Node "Client" and can appear at Document to string regeneration moment.